# How easily to convert Evernote Notebook to Wordpress category

Tags: wordpress, evernote

I have a bunch of Evernote entries, grouped by Notebooks. Want to convert it to WP posts with preserving of formatting. Most of methods described in Internet concerns single posts. The Everpress plugin don't preserve formatting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks, like I get it. Export of Evernote Notebook to html -> wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/